# GidView Reorder Column Should not changed the position after DataBinding

Tags: c#, gridview

I have gridview and after each 20 sec there is method to bind the grid.
user can reorder the columns. so when I m tryuing to bind itemsource it gets rearrange on original position

Comment: Obviously, you just need to remind your filters before updating datasource.

Comment: you need to show relevant code to get help on this web site